# R bigglm() Error: cannot allocate vector of size

Tags: r, glm

When I ran a regression using just glm(), I received an error
"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 128.7 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rep.int(c(1, numeric(n)), n - 1L) :
  Reached total allocation of 8089Mb: see help(memory.size)"
So I decided to use bigglm(), setting chunksize to various numbers, but I still receive the same error. Please help, I am using a dataframe with 380 columns and 340000 rows.

Comment: I tried an example on my PC, but even `glm` worked fine. Can you tell us what kind of GLM you tried? Have you also "cleaned" the memory before using `bigglm`?

Comment: You are trying to fit a glm for a matrix with ~129m elements. You can either 1) find a computer with more memory. 2) find another glm algorithm that is possibly more memory efficient (another glm package for large datasets, I see speedglm from a quick google search). 3) try a new methodology (bagged glm, lasso, etc)

Comment: I'll look into those. I used this GLM:  
model = bigglm(f, data = reg, na.action = na.pass, family = binomial(link=logit), chunksize = 5000)  
Where f is the same as A~.

Comment: Does your formula involve factors, or do your variables include lots of zeros? If so, using a sparse model matrix would require less memory.

Comment: Are you applying your model on data.table ? Try to convert it to data.frame() Worked for me